# referencing a directory from a different project in the properties file of another project

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

I am a Java novice

I am using Eclipse and I have a project (say Main Project) which has in its build path another project (let's call it Second Project).

I need to write in the directories section of the properties file of the Main Project the address of certain files which are part of the Second Project (and as result stored in the Second directory).

Considering the string `properties.dir = ./proj/properties` which is used to reference a directory named `properties` in the Main project, what should I use if this is in the Second project?

The string `properties.dir = Second/proj/properties` wouldn't do the job...

Comment: I'm thinking that you're describing what you think the steps to achieve what you want rather than what you actually want.  Do you actually need to reference the contents of that other file (which you shouldn't have to in Java) or do you want the results of that file (i.e. the class)?

Answer (score 2):

Building on Travis' comment: Are you sure you need to load the files as files?

If you can load them via the class loading mechanism (`Class.getResourceAsStream`), then all you have to do is have the Second Project on your build path.